# How can we create an side menu(sliding menu) in android actionbaractivity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, slidingmenu

I am using android appcompat_v7 version,i had developed an actionbar activity with optionmenu(flowmenu) at the right corner of my action bar,it works fine.Now i want to place a sliding menu at the left corner of action bar,is there any possibility.
I had tried some code but nothing works fine..

Comment: Do you mean a Navigation Drawer?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: I think who have down voted  have to specify reson so OP  know what is problem

Comment: Can you add the code you have tried so far? Will be better for people to help you and sort out which is you actual problem.

Comment: @quicklearner i had tried that example with some modifications.I had add another fragment activity,when i click on the option menu of that particular screen it was hitting mainactivity optionmenu,i had written some functionality of the option menu of that particular activity

Answer (score 0):

Try with a navigation drawer. It is part of the Android Platform, not a third party library, so you could find a whole example here in the official documentation https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the new Android support design library. Check the official [blogspot](http://android-developers.blogspot.gr/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) and some fresh tutorials like [this](http://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view/) are starting to emerge. If you you follow the guidelines you will probably solve any issues. If you use the new library don't forget to add the correct dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a drawerLayout to create a sliding menu.
DrawerLayout is a widget in support-v4.

Here is the documents:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html